# Condor on Win7: connection issue (Errno 10054)

Tags: io, condor

I have installed condor 8.2.0 on several Win7 (32/64bit) computers according this guide: http://www.slideshare.net/gtelzur/condor8-win-install All the services run on the same machine and therefore I rule out a physical network interrupt.

Whenever a job is created/submitted, it stays in the idle mode. A detailed look a the log files unveil the following issue (ShadowLog):

```
07/07/14 08:10:47 (1.1) (PID1): **** condor_shadow (condor_SHADOW) pid PID1 EXITING WITH STATUS 107
07/07/14 08:10:47 (1.0) (PID2): condor_read() failed: recv(fd=540) returned -1, errno = 10054 , reading 5 bytes from startd slot1@mycomputer.mydomain.local.
07/07/14 08:10:47 (1.0) (PID2): IO: Failed to read packet header
07/07/14 08:10:47 (1.0) (PID2): Can no longer talk to condor_starter <192.168.25.120:56186>
```

I couldn't find more details about an IO exception with ID 10054. Beyond that Google does not give me useful hints if I search for "Condor IO: Failed to read packet header".

Do you have a clue what could address the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and it was fixed when I reinstalled Condor in `C:\Condor` (it was in `D:\Condor`).

Note that with Condor 8.2.1 I ran into an unrelated problem: I had to edit the `condor_config` file and remove one $ in the line `CONDOR_HOST = $$(FULL_HOSTNAME)`, as otherwise there was a parsing error.

Comment: I will try to install it to C:\Condor instead of a different drive. Besides that I've already checked the config and the settings were correct (`CONDOR_HOST = $(FULL_HOSTNAME)`).

Answer (score 1):

When you see

`condor_read() failed: .... reading 5 bytes from .....`

In one of the log files, that usually means that the other side of the connection hung up, so you should look in the log file for the other side of the conversion.  In this case, that would be the **StarterLog.slot1** on **mycomputer.mydomain.local**  (or possibly just the **StarterLog**, if the problem happens very early).

Usually when a daemon hangs up, the reason for the hang up is in the log, and very often the problem is that the other side of the conversation isn't authorized.  See configuration values that match ALLOW_* to see what is authorized.